# Updating BIOS - Increase RAM Capacity? Virtual Memory Increase?

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, bios, updates

I have an old laptop.  Does Updating the BIOS increase Maximum RAM capacity?
Sometimes my programs will shut down and the laptop is slow at Max RAM.  RAM is 4gb and Virtual Memory is 5gb.  Google says click Start, Computer (*there is no Computer to click - there is Settings and "Virtual Memory" isn't in TypeToSearch's vocabulary.

How does one increase laptop's Virtual Memory and does Updating BIOS increase physical RAM Capacity in old laptop running Windows 10?  Can I install more RAM than Manufacturer Specified?

Comment: If CPU design helps set Max Physical RAM, I was thinking of trying to put a Quad-Core in place of the Single-Core (awaiting delivery(45nm)).  Your opinion?  I have an 8gbRAM laptop under the couch I don't use but I really do like this one (4gbRAM).  Problem was Intel Specifications don't say what the Max RAM is for many of the Legacy CPU's.  What really sets Max RAM - CPU or Board? thanks for your answer.

Comment: CPU upgrades are often problematic. I do not do them any more. It may or may not work and you would have to try it to see.  I think the laptop is end of life.

Comment: Old Single Core CPU 800Mhz bus, new upgrade Quad Core CPU 1066Mhz bus.  Just read Board (GL40) incompatible in chat from 2012.  I didn't think bus speed mattered much (something about Graphics chip support in GL40 board).

Answer (score 0):

In the general case the answer is "No, an updated BIOS will not help with increasing maximum RAM or VM".   There are some corner cases where manufacturers will cripple systems by limiting the kinds of components that can be added, but this is somewhat uncommon on consumer level laptops.

Much more likely drivers of the maximum amount of RAM a system can take are (a) The CPU used - different CPUs can support different amounts of RAM, and also the number of sockets available and if RAM is soldered on.  Occasionally you can install more RAM then the manufacturer specified, but this would be an edge case where larger RAM sticks became available after the model was sold, but where there was no CPU or hardware bottleneck.  You should never rely on this being possible, as it normally isnt

Virtual Memory is something entirely different - its using disk space as memory.  There are few theoretical limits on what you can do here, however there is a practical limit because HDDs are so slow.  This can - to a limited extent - be worked around by using SSDs, as they are much faster then hard drives (but still slower then real RAM).   Virtual Memory is managed by the OS, and is not really related to BIOS.

Thought - you might want to advise your laptop make and model (If its a Dell, the service tag would be useful to) and we may be able to give you more concrete answers.